# SSL Redirect (no idea where it's coming from)

Tags: ee2, htaccess, ssl

I recently had to do some emergency-work on my client's live server, and wanted to sync those changes back into my repository and staging environment. Now that I've synced them back (copied new files to local, committed them to my repo and pushed to staging) my staging environment and local environment both try to redirect to https:// versions of their frontend. The backend is fine, but fornt-end wants to load over SSL. I don't have DM Force SSL or any other SSL-related plugins installed. Any thoughts as to why this might occur? I've already checked my .htaccess, but that only contains EE's basic URL-rewrite... I'm stumped here.

Thanks,

- Steven

Comment: If it turns out not to be Store, then I'd recommend disabling addons till you find the culprit.

Comment: What was the emergency work that you completed?

Comment: A plugin I used for truncating was magically failing on an important template, needing immediate replacement (during heavy traffic no less).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible culprit - if you have Store installed, and have the `Require SSL connection for checkout and order tags` setting enabled, it would redirect every time you use Store tags on your site over an unencrypted connection.

That might explain why it's only happening on some pages.

Comment: Haha wow, that might very well be it... is this a setting that could be moved over to config.php for future versions so I can disable it for local and staging?

Comment: Yup, that's it. FML. Thanks alot for the quick assist Adrian! Much appreciated!

Comment: Great :) In future you will be able to overwrite all Store settings in `config.php`. Aside from that though, I always recommend using HTTPS in development if you are using it in production, otherwise you end up with these weird issues which only show themselves in production. Your development environment should always resemble as much as possible your production environment.

Comment: I agree about the environments being as close as possible, but an SSL-certificate for a subdomain costs extra (should've gone for a wildcard-certificate, but my client didn't see the need for one)

Comment: If it's only staging, the SSL certificate doesn't need to validate. Just create a self-signed certificate, and ignore the browser errors.

Comment: Also, if you don't know how to create a self signed certificate, there are also companies which offer completely free SSL certificates, which would be more than enough for a staging site, e.g. http://www.startssl.com/

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you copy-paste your URL into this tool: http://redirectcheck.com/index.php ?

Comment: This is the response:

https://gist.github.com/StevenLangbroek/1ff45d2df0aa1eab786c